# How to switch between Linux's virtual consoles?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, vmware-vsphere

I am using vSphere and would like to change to a virtual console in the guest OS.

The problem is that when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> my desktop (Ubuntu) changes virtual console and not the guest OS in vSphere.

Does anyone know to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> , etc. to obtain the other virtual consoles.

**Edit:**

Oh, you're accessing VMWare from a non-Windows machine?

I would just disable virtual console switching on your Ubuntu system. For Xorg, it'll be something like the following in the Xorg config file:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "DontVTSwitch" "true"
EndSection
```

Comment: If the Linux guest is running in console mode, `Alt-Fx` will only switch the guest and not her local machine.

Comment: @mikeyb Let's hope that the VMWare guest is in console mode :) Good point, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way this can be done:

- [Switching between text consoles in a Linux virtual machine (1006012)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1006012)

> Press CTRL + ALT + Space , press the F1 key (or desired Function key)
> while still holding down CTRL + ALT

You could also possibly run `chcon` to change the console, which I've also occassionally found useful before I learned the trick above.